# Join two tables (One to Many) using asp.net core web api

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, webapi

I am new at C# entity framework. I am trying to build an API, but stuck in retrieving data from relational table.
I have a Game table in MS SQL database, where GameId is the primary key. I have another table called GameCharacter, where GameCharacterId is the primary key.
In Game table GameCharacterId is foreign key. How i can get all GameCharacters on Get Games.

```
 public class Game
    {
        public Game()
        {
            GameCharacters = new List<GameCharacter>();
        }
        public int GameID { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Platform { get; set; }
        public string imgpath { get; set; }
        public int ReleaseYear { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection< GameCharacter> GameCharacters { get; set; }
    }
```

```
 public class GameCharacter
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid CharID { get; set; }
        public string CharName { get; set; }
        public string CharGame { get; set; }
        public string charimgpath { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Game")]
        public int GameID { get; set; }
        public virtual Game Game { get; set; }

    }
```

```
 public class GameController : Controller
    {
        private readonly GameApiDbconnect dbContext;

        public GameController(GameApiDbconnect dbContext)
        {
            this.dbContext = dbContext;
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetGames()
        {
            return Ok(await dbContext.Games.ToListAsync());
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("{GameID=guid}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetGame([FromRoute] Guid GameID)
        {
            var game = await dbContext.Games.FindAsync(GameID);
            if (game == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
                return Ok(game);
        }
```

**OutPut**
Response body

{
"gameID": 1,
"title": "string",
"platform": "string",
"imgpath": "string",
"releaseYear": 0,
"gameCharacters": []
}

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetGames()
    {
        return Ok(from g in dbContext.Games
                        join c in dbContext.GameCharacters on g.GameID 
    equals c.GameID into Gcharacters
                        select new
                        {
                            GameID = g.GameID,
                            Title = g.Title,
                            Platform = g.Platform,
                            imgpath = g.imgpath,
                            ReleaseYear = g.ReleaseYear,

                            GameCharacters = Gcharacters.Select(gc => new { 
    CharID = gc.CharID, CharName = gc.CharName, CharGame = 
           gc.CharGame, charimgpath = gc.charimgpath }) }
        ) ;
     }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You should create a class instead of using new, then it would be easier to integrate data in the view without using Dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

just use include

```
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetGames()
        {
           var games = await dbContext.Games
                                       .Include( g=> g.GameCharacters)
                                        .ToListAsync();
            return Ok(games);
        }
```

Comment: @Basit Since you have specifed the Foreign key, this should have been the accepted answer (Cleaner and easier than accepted one...)